# Finding theta and phi for spherical texture mapping

Tags: c++, textures, texture-mapping

for a school project I need to find theta and phi for a spherical texture map. A lot of the actual OpenGL for texturing is already completed (comes with the starter code). The starter code provides the function and comments below. The code is what I have done so far (besides the initialization for x and z, which was given) :

```
Vec3f sphere::getTextureCoords(Vec3f eye, Vec3f dir)
{
    // find the normal (getNormal)
    Vec3f n = this->getNormal(eye, dir);

    // use these to find spherical coordinates
    Vec3f x(1, 0, 0);
    Vec3f z(0, 0, 1);

    // phi is the angle down from z
    // theta is the angle from x curving toward y

    // find phi using the normal and z
    float phi = acos(n.Dot3(z));

    // find the x-y projection of the normal
    Vec3f proj(n.x(), n.y(), 0);

    // find theta using the x-y projection and x
    float theta = acos(proj.Dot3(x));

    // if x-y projection is in quadrant 3 or 4, then theta = 2PI - theta
    if (proj.y() < 0)
        theta = TWOPI - theta;

    Vec3f coords;
    coords.set(theta / TWOPI, phi / PI, 0);
    return coords;
}
```

Following the "instructions" in the comments, this is what I came up with. The texture map does not work though (no errors, the coordinates are just wrong). It is possible that the `getNormal` function is not working correctly but I believe the problem lies in my lack of understanding for spherical coordinates. Please let me know what you believe to be the issue, thanks!

Comment: Note the formulae in the Wikipedia article on [Spherical-cartesian conversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), particularly their use of arctan and the note about [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `proj` is not normalized, you get a wrong result for `theta`.

BTW, your naming of theta and phi is unconventional (it confused me at first). Usually the angle from z is called theta and the angle in the x-y-plane is called phi.

Comment: I see, thanks. Sorry about the naming, that is just how it was given to me.